# How to integrate msg91 api with node

Tags: javascript, express, backend, sms-gateway

I am trying mobile verification with msg91 ..the code run succesfully but msg notsending messagee...it gives the success message ...
my code:

```
router.post('/mobile', async (req, res) =\> {
try {
const sendOtp = new SendOtp(process.env.AUTHKEY);
const mobile = await usermodel.findOne({ mobile: req.body.mobile })
if (!mobile) return res.status(403).send('user not found..')

    const otp =`${ Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000)} `
    console.log(otp);
    
    const  phonenumber  = req.body.mobile
    const newPhoneNumber = '+91' + phonenumber
    // console.log(newPhoneNumber);
    
    sendOtp.send(newPhoneNumber, otp, function (error, data) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(error);
    });
    res.status(201).send({ status: 'TRUE', message: 'OTP SEND' })

} catch (error) {
res.status(200).send({ status: 'failed', message: 'Unable to Send OTP', error })
console.log(error)
}
})
```

responce:
{ message: '326b6774704a343230323437', type: 'success' }
null

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
import msg91 from "msg91";
/**
*OR
*const msg91 = require('msg91').default;
*/

msg91.initialize({authKey: "Your-Auth-Key"});
let sms = msg91.getSMS();

// Send SMS
sms.send("flowId",'mobile':"MOBILE_NUMBER_WITH_COUNTRY_CODE","VAR1":"123"});
```

[Use official MSG91 npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msg91)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34667189)